Why is the Baldwin Effect-transformation of learned behaviors into instinctive ones-a likely result of natural selection?
The Baldwin effect is an evolutionary mechanism that describes how learned behaviors can influence the direction of natural selection. It is postulated that when a learned behavior is advantageous, the members of a population that learn it best survive and pass on the ability to learn that behavior.  Eventually the behavior becomes instinctual.
Why would there be a jump from members of a species being able to learn a behavior very quickly to the members of a species having that behavior instinctually hardwired?  It would seem to me that the ability to learn it quickly and efficiently would reduce the relative benefit of gaining that behavioral ability instinctually since the behavior could be taught and learned without hardwiring it as an instinct.

I think you are wrongly thinking of "instinct" and "ability to learn a specific thing more quickly" as somehow separate, rather than as the same thing to varying degrees.

How well accepted is this hypothetical mechanism? You may be asking a question that doesn't have a definitive answer because it's not accepted as fact.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Sdqg-jn_tBk

@anongoodnurse Strictly speaking, I am suggesting a debunk of a conjecture, namely that good learners of a behavior would be likely, by selection pressures, to integrate the learned behavior into an inborn instinct.  So I am suggesting that the Baldwin Effect conjecture is not logically supported by natural selection.

@BryanKrause The Baldwin Effect "conjecture" is the conjecture that a) fast learners of a helpful behavior survive in a population and are b) likely to eventually give rise to offspring that don't have to learn the behavior at all.  I don't think that the progression from a to b is consistent with natural selection.

No one is going to watch a YouTube video to get information you can write in a post. What @BryanKrause said is enough to counter the hypothesis. Instincts are strong things, and in my experience (mainly with dogs), if a dog picks up a behavior, it's because there's an instinct there already that predisposes the animal to "learn" the behavior in the first place, not the other way around (epigenetic modification excluded).

@JosephHirsch I understand what the Baldwin effect is. I think you are not understanding that biological changes underlying "fast learning" can be the same as those underlying "not needing to learn". That's just the fastest learning you can have: already learned. The Baldwin Effect is not about general learning speeds or anything like that, it's about specialization towards a particular behavior, and suggests that if the random variation in a population that allows some individuals to learn a specific behavior more quickly is heritable, selection moves the population towards instinct.

@BryanKrause So mechanistically perhaps there were genetic (likely polygenetic) behavioral tendencies in a population which might have become unlocked easily by observing the behavior of others who had already learned it, but that those behavioral tendencies might still lead to that behavior emerging eventually.  Those with a stronger tendency, or more genes working in that direction survived and eventually the behavior emerges in individuals readily enough that they may end up doing it fairly early in their lives even if they don't see it performed by another.

Yes, that would accurately describe the Baldwin Effect as I understand it.
